# How to use jQuery to add new HTML to the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prepend

When the button is clicked, I want the new reply to be added to the top by update time desc. 
For example, I added three replies. New reply 3 should on the top.

I tried two methods. It seems like after the page is loaded, click button function can not obtain the new added html.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id ^="submitCommentButton"]').click(function() {

    $('#top').append('<div style="background-color:red"> New reply number </div>'); // method 1

    // $('<div style="background-color:red> New reply number </div>').insertBefore($('#reply_container').children('.each').first()); // method 2
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="reply_container">
  <div id="reply1" class="each">
    <div>reply1</div>
    <button type="button" id="submit1">Submit</button>
  </div>

  <div id="reply5" class="each">
    <div>reply5</div>
    <button type="button" id="submit5">Submit</button>
  </div>

  <div id="reply20" class="each">
    <div>reply20</div>
    <button type="button" id="submit20">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code: `$('#top').append('` will add the given html to the **end** of the selected tag.

You need [prepend()](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
$('#top').prepend('<div style="background-color:red"> New reply number </div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="reply_container">    
    <div id="reply1" class="each">
    <div>reply1</div>
    <button type="button" id="submit1">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div id="reply5" class="each">
    <div>reply5</div>
    <button type="button" id="submit5">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div id="reply20" class="each">
    <div>reply20</div>
    <button type="button" id="submit20">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>

 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
              $('button').click( function(){
              $('#reply1').prepend('<div style="background-color:red"> New reply number </div>');
          });
        });
    </script>
```

second way to add HTML:

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="reply_container">    
    <div id="reply1" class="each">
    <div>reply1</div>
    <button type="button" id="submit1">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div id="reply5" class="each">
    <div>reply5</div>
    <button type="button" id="submit5">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div id="reply20" class="each">
    <div>reply20</div>
    <button type="button" id="submit20">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>

 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
              $('button').click( function(){
              $('<div style="background-color:red"> New reply number </div>').insertBefore('#reply1');
          });
        });
    </script>
```